# Problem with x-axis representation using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a graph with jupyter notebook. The graph is shown in the cell but the x-axis does not attach to the graph but appears at the very end of the cell. When I add `plt.tight_layout`, the following warning comes up `Tight layout not applied. The bottom and top margins cannot be made large enough to accommodate all axes decorations.`

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy import stats

%matplotlib inline

file = pd.read_excel("T8.xlsx","Phthalansäureanhydrid",usecols=[2,3])
X = file['Zeit(s)']
Y = file['Temperatur(Celcius Grad)']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X,Y,'-',color='#10A5F3', label="Phthalansäureanhydrid")
ax.grid(True, which='major', axis='both', color='#F19211', linestyle='-')
#ax.grid(True, which='minor', axis='both', color='#F19211', linestyle='--')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.legend(loc='upper center', frameon=True)

#major & minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(10))

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))




plt.xlabel(r'Zeit[s]')
plt.ylabel(r'Temperatur[c]')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Link to the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xznXj-aA-Szq2s4KWb-qPWYxZbQNrA5FgUCQT6i7oVo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide us the content of the excel, or least the structure and some rows of data, please?

Comment: @powerPixie sorry i forgot to provide the raw data. They can now be found in the post :)

Comment: i think the problem is that the y-axis starts with 24 while the y-axis starts with 0

Comment: You set the bottom spine to zero which is way off the y-axis scale (in this case you'd have to also specifiy `ax.set_ylim(0)`, but I don't think this is what you want). So what should your x axis look like? The chart looks fine to me if you don't set the left and bottom spine position.

Comment: @Stef thanks for the advice. when i comment out the bottom spine everything works out.